# Is it "Get notified on" or "Get notified of"

Tags: prepositions

I am putting together a banner for a trade show to showcase our mobile app, and one of the bullets is: "Get notified on wishlist matches", but I'm not sure if the correct preposition should be on, of, or about.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Be notified _of_ wishlist matches _on_ your profile/your phone/the toilet/time.

Answer (score 4):

Look at it this way, what would you expect in these:

> The app notifies you ____ stuff.
>
> You are notified by the app ____ stuff.
>
> Be notified ____ stuff.
>
> Did you notify her ____ the thing?
>
> Notifications ____ stuff are hard to ignore.
>
> Send them a notification ____ stuff.
>
> The app is notifying them ____ stuff.
>
> That was a notification ____ action taken.

It seems to me like those should all be "*about*", and so should yours.

Having said that, you send a notification *to* someone, and your notify them *of* or *about* something. You should be able to use *"of"* in any of those as well, but it can feel clunky to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

How about **receive notifications about**...?

Answer (score 0):

*Get notification **of** wishlist matches*